# Mount a TrueCrypt volume on iPad

Tags: truecrypt, ipad

I have a TrueCrypt volume that I mount across various operating systems. I'd like to be able to mount this volume on my iPad as well. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: An easy soulution could be mounting the truecrypt volume on a webserver and access it with webdav.

Answer (score 3):

Disk Decipher says it can provide access to TrueCrypt volumes. I think this is what you might be looking for, although I have not tried it out myself.

Comment: I presume you mean [Disk Decipher](http://disk-decipher.hekkihek.nl/).

Answer (score 2):

You can't mount devices into your iPad. So this is not possible.